# CSS styling an form image button, separately?

Tags: html, css, forms, button

I am wanting to have a separate styling for my image buttons in my form so they don't have a white background like the rest of my input elements.

This is an element I want seperate styling for:

```
<input id="confirm_quote" width="60" type="image" height="60" name="confirm_quote" src="img/go.png">
```

This is the defailt style for all input elements:

```
    input
{
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

I would like a seperate styling for input buttons.

I have tried the following but they do not work:

```
    input.button.image
{
    background: none;
}
```

and

```
    input.image
{
    background: none;
}
```

and

```
input image
{
    background: none;
}
```

None seem to work.

Any ideas? Or explanation why this is not working?

Comment: Have you tried this ? : #confirm_quote {
    background: none;
}

Comment: Thanks, but this would only apply to one image button, I have about 20 on my whole website. So I would have to do this for each one :(

Comment: Then you'll have to add a class to your buttons. You could also try Chris' answser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
input[type="image"] {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Should do it...

Comment: Thanks for this, could you explain this syntax to me

Comment: It will simply target any and all input elements which have the value "image" in their attribute "type". You can use any attribute you like to achieve the same results. There are a few different variations you can use too ([see MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Attribute_selectors)).

Answer (score 1):

you have to try this css.

```
input[type=image]
{
background-image:your-image path;
width-size;
height-size;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-color:transparent;
border:0px;
}
```